# Cheerio not working. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, cheerio

I am trying to scrape a classified ad search result page.

I have tried console logging everything I can to make sure I am getting a response, which I am, but when I actually use cheerio to query something I don't get anything back. For instance if I just query for how many children using `$('.listing-group').children('section').length` I get back `0` instead of `24` when I console log it.

Here is what I'm doing. Pardon the long URL.

```
const request = require("request");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const app = express();

app.get("/scrape", function(req, res) {
  url =
    "http://classifieds.ksl.com/search/?keyword=code&category%5B%5D=Books+and+Media&zip=&miles=25&priceFrom=&priceTo=&city=&state=&sort=";

  request(url, function(error, response, html) {
    if (!error) {
      let $ = cheerio.load(html);

      let test = $("#search-results").find("section").length

      console.log(test);

    } else {

      console.log("there has been an error");

    }

    res.send("Check the console.");

  });
});

app.listen("8081");
console.log("check localhost:8081/scrape");
exports = module.exports = app;
```

I'm new to cheerio so I'm assuming I'm probably making a simple error, but with all the tutorials I've checked, I can't seem to find an answer.

Ultimately I want to grab each result on the page (found in the 'section' tags) to display the data for a personal project I'm working on.

Comment: If you "view source" on that page you'll see that the listing data is in a json blob in the middle of that page. So you need to extract that with regex and JSON.parse() it.

Comment: @pguardiario Thanks for the help. I dug around and this is what I came up with. `let newStr = html.match(/\{\"id\"(.*)\"free\"\}/gm)` That grabs that blob, but then when I try to parse it with `let newstr = JSON.parse(html.match(/\{\"id\"(.*)\"free\"\}/gm))` I get an error. Any further guidance? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like:

```
JSON.parse(html.match(/listings: (\[.*\])/)[1])
```

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you very much. I'm quite new to regex and I have no idea what I'm doing with it.